# Update GPU Usage in Viewport [ Evee Next… ]

Tags: 3d-view, gpu

I just would like to know if there is a list of all features in Blender calculated by the Gpu instead of Cpu in viewport in Evee (Next) - Hydra - Workbench ?

It make sense to have this kind of informations when it’s time to update our PC hardware.

Thanks.